# How to plot a scatter plot over a base map projection?

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

Below is my code trying to plot scatter points on top of a base map projection of some other data. 
I have the actual path to the data in my code.

The scatter points wont show overtop of the base map projection.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid, cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib as mpl
samosdata = Dataset()
d = Dataset()


sst = d.variables["analysed_sst"][:][0, ::-1, :]  
lon = d.variables["lon"][:]
lat = d.variables["lat"][::-1]
lats = samosdata.variables['lat']
lons = samosdata.variables['lon']
time = samosdata.variables['time']
ts = samosdata.variables['TS']
ts = np.array(ts)

lons = np.array(lons)
lats = np.array(lats)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=-80, urcrnrlat=80,
        llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, lat_ts=20, resolution='c')

nx = int((m.xmax - m.xmin)/11113.2); ny = int((m.ymax m.ymin)/11113.2)
sst = m.transform_scalar(sst, lon, lat, nx, ny)
im = m.imshow(sst, interpolation = "none")


x, y =m(list(lons), list(lats)) 
pts = plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', s=5, c=ts, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(pts)
m.drawcoastlines()
parallels = np.arange(-90, 90, 30)
meridians = np.arange(-180, 180, 60)
m.drawparallels(parallels, labels = [1, 0, 0, 1])
m.drawmeridians(meridians, labels = [1, 0, 0, 1])

cb = m.colorbar(im, "right", size = "5%", pad = "2%")
ax.set_title("SST 2010 01 01")
plt.show()
```

When I input this for the bounds it will plot the scatter points but wont accuratly show the background data.

```
m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=min(lats)-30, 
urcrnrlat=max(lats)+30,
        llcrnrlon=min(lons)-30, urcrnrlon=max(lons)+30, lat_ts=20, 
resolution='c')
```

Comment: You should share your data file. It doesn't need to be the real big one, but with similar structure but smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function `plt.scatter()` with `m.scatter()`. And use option `latlon=True` should solve your problem

```
...
pts = m.scatter(x,y, marker='o', s=5, c=ts, cmap='plasma', latlon=True)
...
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: So now when I make those adjustments I get the error.   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().  from the line in my come.    "pts = m.scatter(x,y, marker='o', s=5, c=ts, cmap='plasma', latlon=True)"  Any advice on this?

Comment: No idea without data file to run/explore.